# How to allow user to multiple photo selection to upload?

Tags: iphone, ios

I found flicker and dropbox allow to upload multiple selection of photo and upload at a time. I am working on one application where I need such functionality.

Can anyone help me on that or provide reference link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at [ELCImagePickerController project](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) on GitHub. It's using AssetsLibrary framework to build a custom image selection controller